# add image to android app without eclipse

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

hey guys I am doing an app for android, without using Eclipse and without using the layout.xml 
for example this creates button and text for me just fine :

```
Button btn1 = new Button(this);
btn1.setText("Click Me");
final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("Hello world");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.addView(btn1);
ll.addView(tv1);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.addView(ll);
sv.setFillViewport(true);
setContentView(sv);
```

could you tell me how can I add an image to my app without using eclipse ?

I copied my image to res/drawable folder I was thinking maybe I could add it like a TextView to my LinearLayout something like this

```
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource(// dont know what to put here);
    ll.add(image)
```

any ideas? ( i dont know wanna use eclispe)

Comment: have you try `
image.setImageResource(R.id.your_image_name)`?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ? Wich IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a NullPointerException I bet?

Try this:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // You're probably also going to want to maintain the aspect ration, so set this to true.
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_of_resource_without_extension)); // ie. R.drawable.mypic
```

That is assuming it is in the "drawable" or a derivative's folder.

You need to initialize the Object before you try to use it's functions unless they're statically accessible.

Comment: Thanks after that how do I say load that image file name in my package folder , let say I wanna load mypic.jpg?

Comment: java:54: error: no suitable method found for getResources(int)
image.setImageResource(getResources(R.drawable.england))
;method ContextThemeWrapper.getResources() is not applicable
aactual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ContextWrapper.getResources() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     method Context.getResources() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] 1 error

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's because I was an idiot. I have no idea why I typed that... It's updated

Comment: Just glad I could help~

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize it first. I know you would do that. Then:
    image.setImageResource(getResources(R.drawable.IMAGE));
or
    setBackgroundResource();

Comment: I get this error : java:53: error: no suitable method found for getResources(int)
    [javac]             image.setImageResource(getResources(R.drawable.england))
;
    [javac]     method ContextThemeWrapper.getResources() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     method ContextWrapper.getResources() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     method Context.getResources() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)